# Must a external js file contain a .js extension?

Tags: javascript

Is it okay if I use `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/file"></script>`

without .js at the end of the source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's okay to omit the `.js`, as long as your server is configured to cope with that and will serve that URI with a `200 OK` and `Content-Type: text/javascript`.

Comment: The content-type doesn't even have to match.  You can technically put anything you want in there but you'll get warnings if it's anything other than a JS content type, e.g. if I try a .jpg chrome says `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg` (and then of course throws a JS parsing error)